# ¿cómo obtener totales por grupos en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo que crear un reporte en php:

1. consulta de clientes ordenado en asc.
2. sumar el total de la ventas de cada cliente.
3. sumar total de las ventas por día.
4. sumar el total de todos los clientes.

Todo esto por un rango de fechas:

```
select fecha, razonsocial , precioTotal 
from ventas 
 LEFT JOIN clientes 
   ON idClientes = clientes_idClientes
where fecha BETWEEN '2016-11-30 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-30 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY razonsocial ASC
```

[image: reporte a crear]

[image: consulta en mysql]

Me dicen que los datos importantes son los totales que no tiene que llevar las ventas del día, solo les importa los totales.

Esta es mi estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ventas` (
  `idVenta` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `fecha_pago` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `nota` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `factura` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `porcDescuento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1 Credito 2 Contado 3 Pendiente de pago 4 Pagado 5 Cancelada ',
  `cantidad` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `peso` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unidad` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1 pza 2 gr 3 kg',
  `precioTotal` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `cancelacion` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productos_idProducto` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `usuarios_idUsuario` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `clientes_idClientes` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `empleados_idRepartidor` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `Observaciones` text,
  `ObservCancelacion` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idVenta`),
  KEY `fk_ventas_clientes1_idx` (`clientes_idClientes`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5975 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clientes` (
  `idClientes` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `aPaterno` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `aMaterno` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `razonsocial` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rfc` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `calle` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1 credito 2 contado 3 Pendiente de pago',
  `tel` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cel` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activo` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `estados_idEstado` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `municipios_idMunicipio` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `colonias_idColonia` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `sucursales_idSucursal` int(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idClientes`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=49 ;

ALTER TABLE `ventas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_ventas_clientes1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`clientes_idClientes`)
  REFERENCES `clientes` (`idClientes`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

**[Edición]**

Maestros ya tengo 2 consultas de 3 que me ayudo el compañero @marcelolemus

1- Sumar el total de la ventas de cada cliente.

select razonsocial , SUM(precioTotal) from ventas LEFT JOIN clientes ON idClientes = clientes_idClientes WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2016-11-30 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-30 23:59:59' group by razonsocial

3- Sumar el total de todos los clientes

select SUM(preciototal) from ventas WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2016-11-30 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-30 23:59:59'

**2- Sumar total de las ventas por día
select SUM(preciototal) from ventas**

select SUM(preciototal) from ventas

lo intente con este query  y me marca error que no existe el campo fecha pero si tengo el campo

select SUM(preciototal) as totalpordia from ventas WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2016-11-30 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-30 23:59:59' group by fecha(datetime)

lo modifique pero solo me da 1 registro por cada cliente de de la venta entre esas fechas

select SUM(preciototal) as totalpordia from ventas WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2016-11-30 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-30 23:59:59' group by fecha

dormire un poco a lo mejor me falta acabo de llegar del turno de la noche jeje gracias de verdad a veces entre sueños sale la respuesta jeje.

Comment: Hola Carlos, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Para responder esta pregunta sin ambigüedades no es suficiente con la información que proporciona. ¿Es posible que añada a su pregunta las columnas de las dos tablas y las relaciones entre estas?

Comment: Si peimitame llegar a casa voy saliendo del trabajo

Comment: @dwarandae ya subi la relacion y las tablas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pareciera ser bastante fácil lo que consultas, diría que solo usando SUM() en la consulta podrás obtener todos los valores.

Respecto a ordenar las razón social, recomiendo pasar todos los resultados a una matriz reemplazando los valores por las cadenas definitivas (nombre de clientes) y luego ordenarla por lo que necesites (sort, por ejemplo).

1. Sumar el total de la ventas de cada cliente.

   ```
   select razonsocial, SUM(preciototal) from ventas group gy razonsocial
   ```
2. Sumar total de las ventas por día

   ```
   select  SUM(preciototal) as totalpordia from ventas group by fecha(date)
   ```
3. Sumar el total de todos los clientes

   ```
   select SUM(preciototal) from ventas
   ```

Comment: ya tengo el primer query señor @marcelolemus  sigamos !!!!                                           select razonsocial , SUM(precioTotal) from ventas LEFT JOIN clientes ON idClientes = clientes_idClientes WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2016-11-30 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-30 23:59:59' group by razonsocial

Comment: 3- suma el total de todos los clientes                                                                  select SUM(preciototal) from ventas WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2016-11-30 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-30 23:59:59'