# Sentencia en MySQL para contar los registros ingresados por hora

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada records con las siguientes columnas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de crear una sentencia que me permita obtener el total de mensajes por hora y el total  de clasificados por la columna status y esto agrupado por la columna start_time, siendo el campo status con valor 1, 2 y 3 y campo start_time un dato de tipo datetime. Hasta el momento tengo la siguiente sentencia:

```
SELECT 
    start_time,
    COUNT(status) as callsbyhour,
    (SELECT COUNT(status) FROM records HAVING status = 1 AND id = R.id ) AS  totalStatus1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records WHERE status = 2 AND R.start_time = start_time ) AS totalStatus2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records WHERE status >= 2 AND id = R.id) AS totalStatus3
FROM 
    records R
WHERE
    start_time >= '2018-07-02 06:00:00'
AND
    start_time < '2018-07-03 05:59:59'
GROUP BY
    HOUR(start_time)
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

El total por hora me lo da correctamente, pero el total por estatus agrupado por hora no muestra lo esperado, haciendo una prueba me arroja lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto es incorrecto ya que de las 11 llamadas totales 7 son con estatus 1, 0 con estatus 2, y 3 con estatus 3.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

**Actualización 07-09-2018 18:07**

Amigos,

Encontré la solución dejo la consulta por si a alguien le llegara a servir.

```
SELECT 
start_time,
COUNT(status) as callsbyhour,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(status) FROM records WHERE status = 1 AND start_time = R.start_time)) AS  totalStatus1,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(status) FROM records WHERE status = 2 AND start_time = R.start_time )) AS totalStatus2,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(status) FROM records WHERE status >= 3 AND start_time =     R.start_time)) AS totalStatus3
FROM 
records R
WHERE
start_time >= '2018-07-02 06:00:00'
AND
start_time < '2018-07-03 05:59:59'
GROUP BY HOUR(start_time)
ORDER BY 1
```

Parte de la solución la encontré en esta pregunta:

[¿cómo obtener totales por grupos en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36975/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-totales-por-grupos-en-mysql?rq=1)

Gracias comunidad!!!

Comment: Ya probaste usar alguna variable que guarde el "R.id" dentro del select puede quedar algo asi **@id:=R.id** Y en tu COUNT AND id = **@id** ) AS  totalStatus1,

Comment: Si pudieras agregar la tabla record y ambas tablas con algunos datos me podrías ayudar a visualizar mejor el problema y así ayudarte. Puedes?

Comment: Date cuenta que está mal tu sentencia, aquí `status = 1 AND id = R.id` estás condicionando que el i = R.id, lo cual obviamente siempre arrojará 1 o 0 ya que solo existiría un registro con ese id, tienes que comprararlos por el tiempo como hiciste en el count del status 2

Comment: @Sr1871 ya probé de la forma que comentas pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo, me arroja los mismos valores que muestro en la imagen

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav actualizo con una imagen de la tabla records en sí contiene más columnas pero para la consulta sólo necesito la información de las que muestro, la sentencia sólo aplica a esta tabla

Comment: @EfrenAnastacio `de las 11 llamadas totales 7 son con estatus 1` = ¿en qué rango de fecha?, si uso el de su ejemplo, obtengo 8.

Comment: Que bueno que lograras solventarlo, trata de responder tu propia pregunta para que ya salga como respondida